# Extract inner color of cell and apply that to text in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I've managed to extract the text color from original cells, but would like to instead use the inner cell color (back ground color).

`uyuy` should be lightblue instead of green (in H8).
`pp` (first one) should be gray instead of red (in H8).

Is possible to do it?

[image]

Macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      Dim rngFormula As Range: Set rngFormula = Me.Range("H5:Q5")
      If Not Intersect(Target, rngFormula) Is Nothing Then
            Dim aC As Range, rngCol As Range, rngPr As Range, c As Range, strCell As String, startCh As Long
            Dim firstCh: firstCh = 1 'to start searching after the word has been found!
            ReDim arrUsed(rngFormula.Cells.Count - 1)
            Set aC = Me.Range("H7")
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                If aC.HasFormula Then
                     Set rngCol = aC.Offset(1)
                     strCell = aC.Value: rngCol = strCell
                     Set rngPr = aC.Precedents
                     For Each c In rngPr.Cells
                             startCh = InStr(firstCh, strCell, c.Value)
                             rngCol.Characters(startCh, Len(c.Value)).Font.Color = c.Font.Color
                             firstCh = startCh + Len(c.Value)
                     Next c
                   End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't change part of a cell's background colour if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @SSlinky not change the background color... but use the background color of the original text... to color the output text in H8.... I've managed to use the text color in row 5... but not the background color.

Comment: Please, use `rngCol.Characters(startCh, Len(c.value)).Font.Color = c.Interior.Color` instead of `rngCol.Characters(startCh, Len(c.value)).Font.Color = c.Font.Color`.

Answer (score 0):

To set the text colour of one cell based on the text colour of another's background:

```
rangeWithText.Font.Color = rangeWithBg.Interior.Color
```